# How can I use Regex to differentiate between a fully uppercase word, and an uppercase word attached to a lower case character with missing whitespace?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, nlp, text-mining

Apologies for the convoluted title. I am trying to process text, with some undesirable features: some words are all in upper-case, such as 'EXAMPLE WORD', whilst in other cases there are two words attached, with missing whitespace, as in 'exampleWord'. How can I use regular expressions to separate the two attached words based on the lower-case > upper-case pattern, without affecting the words completely in upper case?

I am currently using

.apply(lambda x: re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", x))

across that column in a Pandas data frame. This inserts a space before each capital letter, transforming upper case letters into a string of individual characters.

I would like a regex expression to only detect when a lowercase character is followed immediately by an upper case character, to separate the words at that point, which would solve the issue of having to affect the words in uppercase. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with lookarounds:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.replace('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', regex=True)
```

Example:

```
            col           new
0  EXAMPLE WORD  EXAMPLE WORD
1   exampleWord  example Word
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XPSGP2/1)

```
(?<=[a-z])  # match lowercase before
(?=[A-Z])   # match uppercase after
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *lookahead assertion*

```
re.sub("([A-Z])(?=[a-z])", r" \1", x)
```

will only match uppercase when it is followed by a lowercase character.